# Problems retrieving EnityManagerFactory in an stateless EJB Bean

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, entitymanager

I'm having difficulties to persist UserEntitys on my JavaDB from an ejb Project. I tried a couple of solutions from various google searches but non seem to help me.

I'm using GlassFish 4 and the JavaDB which comes with it.

This is my Statlessbean which needs the EntityManager
It should be injected by the container through @PersistenceContext as far as I understand.

```
@Stateless
public class UserManagementBean implements UserManagementLocal, UserManagementRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ChatDB")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @EJB
    private ChatManagementLocal chatManagement;
    @EJB
    private StatisticManagementLocal statisticManagement;

    //...

    @Override
    public void login(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(String username) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void registerUser(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        TypedQuery<UserEntity> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("UserEntity.singleUser", UserEntity.class);
        query.setParameter("username", username);

        UserEntity foundUser;

        try {
            foundUser = query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            foundUser = new UserEntity();
            foundUser.setLoggedIn(false);
            foundUser.setUsername(username);
            foundUser.setPassword(generateHash(password));

            entityManager.persist(foundUser);
            chatManagement.sendRegisterMessage(username);
        }

        throw new Exception("Der Benutzername ist bereits vergeben.");
    }

    public String generateHash(String password { ... }
}
```

---

project-ejb

--META-INF

----persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ChatDB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/ChatDB</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>Chat-common.jar</jar-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

project-ear

--META-INF

----glassfish-resources.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC
"-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="ChatDBPool"
            res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"
            datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="1527" />
        <property name="databaseName" value="chat" />
        <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
        <property name="user" value="APP" />
        <property name="password" value="APP" />
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true"
        jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/ChatDB"
        pool-name="ChatDBPool" />
</resources>
```

---

Console

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy286.registerUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName ChatDB
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:138)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:544)
at de.fh_dortmund.inf.cw.chat.server.beans.UserManagementBean.registerUser(UserManagementBean.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at  com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
at  com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
at  com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
... 19 more
```

---

At this point I have no idea on how to start on this issue, what have I missed? What should I check? What further details do you need?

Comment: If it cannot instantiate a JPA provider then either the persistence.xml is not found, or the persistence-unit is not found, or the JPA provider jars are not found. That's all there is

Comment: @BillyFrost Where would I check for the exact reason why it failed to retrieve?

Comment: dont assume "it" will tell you the exact reason. You'll have to inspect your deployment and checks each of those things, and compare with what the docs for that JavaEE server says for use of JPA

Comment: So I created this project structure via the Eclipse Project Wizard, is this in general the right place for the .xml files?

Comment: Check the spelling of your persistence.xml file. It is incorrect in at least one place above, where it is spelt with ...ance.

Comment: @SteveC wow thank you, I’ll check that as soon as I get home

Comment: @SteveC sorry i didn’t get back. You actually solved all my problems. If you post as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
project-ejb 
--META-INF 
----persistance.xml
```

looks suspicious.

You appear to have mis-spelt "persistence.xml".